# understanding python data encoding issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, character-encoding

i am getting some data from facebook by using requests.This is the sample data.

```
response = {'message': 'I have recommended your  name to all my family n friend
s. Thankyou!!!!\\ud83d\\ude0a\\ud83d\\ude0a\\ud83e\\udd17\\ud83e\\udd17\\ud83d\\udc4c\\ud83d\\udc4c\\ud83d\\udc4d\\ud83d\\udc4
}
```

The last few characters are emojis. but when i need to save it in database.

so i try to convert it into a dictionay first so that i can add keys & manipulate data:

```
response = json.loads(response.content, encoding='utf-8')
```

but when i do `print(response)` i get something like

```
       {
'message': 'I have recommended your  name to all my family n friend
        s. Thankyou!!!!__ __ __ __ __ __ __
        }
```

and from db i get this error:

```
Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\x8A\xF0\x9F...'
```

what is the encoding i got ? how do i transform it so that i can store it in databse(mysql)

Answer (score 1):

you can either use the unicodedata:

```
title = u"Klüft skräms inför på fédéral électoral große"
import unicodedata
unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', title).encode('ascii','ignore')
'Kluft skrams infor pa federal electoral groe'
```

or just replace the characters with your own specified characters for later use as emojis:

```
>>> a=u"aaaàçççñññ"
>>> type(a)
<type 'unicode'>
>>> a.encode('ascii','ignore')
'aaa'
>>> a.encode('ascii','replace')
'aaa???????'
>>>
```

Or first encode it into a particular representation that can be stored. There are several common Unicode encodings, such as UTF-16 (uses two bytes for most Unicode characters) or UTF-8 (1-4 bytes / codepoint depending on the character), etc. To convert that string into a particular encoding, you can use:

```
>>> s= u'£10'
>>> s.encode('utf8')
'\xc2\x9c10'
>>> s.encode('utf16')
'\xff\xfe\x9c\x001\x000\x00'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is unicode.  You have To decode string when storing and encode when printing